# Laravel route middleware can:view not being called, getting 403 forbidden error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 7. I have created UserPolicy with all those resource methods.

In my route/web.php I have added another route to the UserController custom method ie.

```
Route::get('user/somefunction', 'UserController@somefunction')->name('user.somefunction')->middleware('can:view');
```

However when I call user/somefunction using my brower, I got 403 forbidden.

I have added a log debug in my UserPolicy view function, it's not getting called at all.

Please advise.

Comment: Is it entering can middleware?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, has to add the model name to middleware. ie

```
Route::get('user/somefunction', 'UserController@somefunction')->name('user.somefunction')->middleware('can:view, App\User');
```